# Can I use a scalar function to take a user input then do a calculation?

Tags: sql, database, scalar

I have a database of athletes.

I want to create a function that takes in an athletes name then calculates their BMI.

So I have

```
Name | Weight | Height
Ath1 |  200   |   61
```

If user inputs Ath1, I want it to spit out the BMI. Is this possible?

Comment: why not? a function will return a value and you can use the value. i bet the question is how to create a function

Comment: Yes that's the question. Never had to do this before. Tried looking around online but found a ton of different answers that didn't involve string input.

Comment: It is possible, but the actual syntax on how to do that depends on the DBMS you are using. So: which DBMS _are_ you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I pray those numbers are [imperial, not metric](http://www.bmi-calculator.net/bmi-formula.php)!